# Parsing CSV header into list of parsers

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I want to parse first line of CSV file and to get list of parsers as a result, and fail miserably.

After some simplifications I got code I think should work, but it does not, and I don't understand why.

Here it is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Control.Applicative

doTestSep :: [String] -> Parser [String]
doTestSep t = do
      (endOfLine >> return t)
  <|> (char ';'  *> doTestParse t)

doTestParse :: [String] -> Parser [String]
doTestParse t = do
      (string "<FIELD1>" *> doTestSep ("field1" : t))
  <|> (string "<FIELD2>" *> doTestSep ("field2" : t))

test = parseOnly (doTestParse []) "<FIELD1>"
```

I call `test`, expecting to get something like

```
> Right ["field1"]
```

but instead I get

```
> Left "Failed reading: takeWith"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The documentation for `endOfLine` says: "Match either a single newline character '\n', or a carriage return followed by a newline character "\r\n".". However, your input doesn't contain either "\n" or "\r\n" so that parser will fail.

Comment: @bennofs thanks, you are right. It works, and my question is a question of blind man.

Comment: Note that there are several good CSV libraries for Haskell depending on your tastes, and Real World Haskell has a section on using parsec to write a CSV parser which you can look to for inspiration if you'd like to roll your own.

Comment: @AndrewC yeah, I looked into that RWH chapter, but found it is not useful for my case. I want a chain of parsers to be created from the first line of file, which contains titles of columns, and an example in my question is oversimplified just to make clear the problem I had.

Also, I like the idea that got into my brain, and want first to try to make it work, before using other libraries.

Comment: Grand. Anyway, good to know you've resolved your problem. Could you pop your answer into the answer box instead of in the question please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is wrong input: my title line will definitely have `\n` or `\r\n`, which will be catched by `endOfLine`, and my example input did not have `\n` in it.

Working version is

```
test = parseOnly (doTestParse []) "<FIELD1>\n"
```